# Where is the Django Administration's view?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin

I am trying to modify the original Django administration template. I successfully managed to add custom content. But I would need this content to appear only when a table in my database is empty. Thus, I would like to pass some content to the template via the view but I cannot find it.

To be more specific, my extended admin template looks like this:

```
{% overextends "admin/index.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls %}

{% block content  %}
     {{ block.super }}

     {% if is_empty %}
         <a href="#">This hyperlink appears only when the table is empty</a>
     {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

and I would like to pass to the template to the variable is_empty either True or False, depending on whether the table is empty or not.

Any ideas how to do that?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a [template context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) that calculates the value of `is_empty`.

```
# in my_app/context_processors.py
from my_app.models import MyTable

def is_empty(request):
    """Returns a bool depending on whether MyTable is empty"""
    return {'is_empty': not MyTable.objects.exists()}
```

Add your context processor to your template settings (note this step is slightly different for Django < 1.8).

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
                'my_app.context_processors.is_empty',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

You can then include `{{ is_empty }}` in any templates rendered with a request context. This includes admin views, generic class based views, and views that use the `render` shortcut.

Comment: Ok, I made that: the only fix I had to make in order not to get an exception was to do `return {"is_empty": not MyTable.objects.exists()}`. Otherwise, absolutely perfect! Thanks!